# Ordering numbers but keeping 0's at the end of the tab

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I want to order a column in e bidimensionnal array (ascending order) but keeping all the 0 at the end. 
For exemple :

```
input = {5,2,1,0,4}
output = {1,2,4,5,0}
```

I've done this method which orders the numbers (ascending) but i don't find how to keep the 0's at the end. (there can be multiple 0)

```
public static void orderCol(int[][] tab, int iCol){ // This will order numbers in the column i (ascending AND placing 0 at the end) (In case the user didnt already do it in the input file this will prevent further problems).
    int temp;
    for(int i=0; i< tab[0].length-1;i++){
        if(tab[iCol][i+1] < tab[iCol][i]){
            //swapping
            temp = tab[iCol][i];
            tab[iCol][i] = tab[iCol][i+1];
            tab[iCol][i+1] = temp;
            i=-1;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help, thanks in advance !

Comment: you might want to look into **rotation of an array**. You could rotate the array after the array is sorted.

Comment: You have just to add a new condition, and ask if that value is 0 , then you swap to the end

Answer (score 0):

you can first count how many 0's does your array have and create a new array with only the non-0s then sort the non-0s and append the 0's

```
public int[] orderCol(int[][] tab, int iCol){ // This will order numbers in the column i (ascending AND placing 0 at the end) (In case the user didnt already do it in the input file this will prevent further problems).
    int index = 0;
    int[] newArray = new int[tab[0].length];
    for (int  x: tab[0]) { // iterates each element on tab[0]
        if (x != 0) newArray[index++] = x;
    }

// SORT YOUR newArray HERE using any sort algo

     while(index != tab[0].length) newArray[index++] = 0;
     return newArray;

}
```